# How can the Planet Labs TMS be used with GDAL?

Tags: gdal, tile-map-service

How can Planet Labs' mosaic Tile Map Service (TMS) be used with [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html) like in the [OpenLayers example](https://www.planet.com/docs/v0/tutorials/ol3-mosaic-tiles.html)? The API requires authentication and other specific settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following XML template can be used in GDAL for Planet Labs mosaics:

`<GDAL_WMS>
    <!-- Planet Labs -->
    <Service name="TMS">
        <ServerUrl>https://tiles.planet.com/v0/mosaics/color_balance_mosaic/${z}/${x}/${y}.png</ServerUrl> 
        <SRS>EPSG:3857</SRS>
        <ImageFormat>image/png</ImageFormat>
        <Transparent>TRUE</Transparent>
    </Service>
    <DataWindow>
        <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
        <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
        <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
        <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>
        <TileLevel>15</TileLevel>
        <TileCountX>1</TileCountX> 
        <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
        <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
    </DataWindow>
    <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
    <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
    <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
    <BandsCount>4</BandsCount>
    <ZeroBlockHttpCodes>204,303,400,404,500,501</ZeroBlockHttpCodes>
    <ZeroBlockOnServerException>true</ZeroBlockOnServerException>
    <MaxConnections>5</MaxConnections>
    <UserPwd>API_KEY</UserPwd>
    <Cache>
        <Path>/tmp/cache_planetlabs.tms</Path>
    </Cache>
</GDAL_WMS>`

Replace `API_KEY` with your actual API key and possibly set the mosaic name to something other than `color_balance_mosaic`. You can also change the location in `<Path>` to a suitable location on your computer or remove the entire `<Cache>` section if you don't want to cache tiles locally.

Disclamer: I work for Planet Labs.